# Board file usage with device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I understood that device tree was introduce to replace board files. But it seems the compatible property of root node is using to match the board file.
Any specific reason of using board file with device tree?

Comment: *"Any specific reason of using board file with device tree?"* -- Perhaps initialization code that is board-level or board-specific, and doesn't belong in a device driver?  Did you investigate further to see how or where those compatible strings were defined and used?

Comment: In board files, these compatible strings are filled in a character pointer array and this array is assigned to dt_compact member of a structure defined using DT_MACHINE_START. Few references, https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/arch/arm/mach-imx/mach-imx6ul.c#L87 , https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/arch/arm/mach-bcm/board_bcm2835.c#L38

Comment: @user3693586, side note: use always `latest` in the Elixir URLs (in your links it's `v4.6` above).

Comment: @user3693586, I guess it's easy to answer. ARM supports the multi-arch kernel and they need to know which platform kernel supports on early stages. Check this: _93c02ab40ae6 ("arm/dt: probe for platforms via the device tree")_ and this _85cad1b0b640 ("arm/dt: Add dt machine definition")_. Basically, just go with `git log -- arch/arm/include/asm/mach/arch.h`.

Comment: @0andriy, sure, I will use latest version when using Elixir URLs. Gone through the commits and understood how the matching machine_desc will be identified. After identifying the matching machine_desc, at what time(from where) the function pointers assigned to the machine_desc will be called.